Copy and paste commands notifier
When I change the language I get a popover notifier which tells what language is currently selected:

How can I get some sort of notifier popover or an alert sound when I copy something or I press the keys cmd + C? I need this specially in vscode while coding.

You can hack it together without any extension by doing the following:
Paste the following in settings.json:
"accessibility.signals.terminalBell": {
    "sound": "on",
    "announcement": "auto",
},

Paste the following into keybindings.json:
{
    "key": "ctrl+c",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": { "commands": [
        {
            "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
            "args": {"text": "echo $'\\a'\u000D"}
        },
        "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
    ]},
    "when": "!isMac",
},
{
    "key": "cmd+c",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": { "commands": [
        {
            "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
            "args": {"text": "echo $'\\a'\u000D"}
        },
        "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
    ]},
    "when": "isMac",
},

If you want it to affect copying from other things like the Explorer View or Problems Panel, you'll need to follow the pattern above for other builtin keybindings bound to ctrl/cmd+c (adding corresponding when clauses from the default bindings). Ex.
{
    "key": "ctrl+c",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": { "commands": [
        {
            "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
            "args": {"text": "echo $'\\a'\u000D"}
        },
        "problems.action.copy",
    ]},
    "when": "!isMac && (problemsVisibility && !relatedInformationFocus && focusedView == 'workbench.panel.markers.view')",
},
{
    "key": "cmd+c",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": { "commands": [
        {
            "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
            "args": {"text": "echo $'\\a'\u000D"}
        },
        "problems.action.copy",
    ]},
    "when": "isMac && (problemsVisibility && !relatedInformationFocus && focusedView == 'workbench.panel.markers.view')",
},

Now if you'll excuse me, I have to undo a configuration change that I find annoying.

Is there anyway to change the beep sound?
